How to fix being unable to revert back from Vampire Lord?
I was doing the Companions' questline (after the Dawnguard questline), trying to become a werewolf when my friend told me about a method that allows you to be both a Vampire Lord and a werewolf. I tried to do it, but foolishly did not save my game beforehand.
To be both a Vampire Lord and a werewolf, you have to transform into a Vampire Lord and drink the werewolf blood while turning. I tried to do the exploit, and it failed (according to my friend). I transformed and did the whole waking-up-in-a-forest part, then I turned into a Vampire Lord (which was part of the exploit that failed, just delayed). Then, when I tried to revert it and do the new quest, I couldn't (the power menu will not show up), and now I'm stuck in Vampire Lord form, but I still am a werewolf, just not transformed (and I can't cast the Vampire Lord spells or open the map, but I can punch and open the vampire perk menu).
My last save is gone, and the last working one is from 3 months ago.
I've tried curing myself, making myself a vampire again, riding a horse, and dying, as well as loading new areas—none of it helped. I also can enter first-person mode, which you can't normally do when transformed as a Vampire Lord.
I'm on PS5 and not using any mods.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Some people on the Internet are saying that the Favorites Menu might have a Revert Form option?
